# Strings in Erlang - what libraries and techniques should I be examining?

Tags: string, erlang, utf

I am working on a project that will require internationalisation support down the track. I want to get started on the right foot with UTF support, and I was wondering what the best practice for handling UTF in Erlang is?

From my current research it seems there are a couple of issues with Erlang's built in string handling for some use cases (JSON parsing being a good example).

I have been looking at [Starling](http://code.google.com/p/starling/) and read (somewhere) recently that it is possibly going to be rolled into the standard Erlang release as the UTF 'standard'. Is this true? Are there other libraries or approaches I should be looking at?

From the comments:

EEP (Erlang Enhancement Proposal) 10 details [Representing Unicode characters in Erlang](http://erlang.org/eeps/eep-0010.html)

Comment: Mochijson2 encodes and decodes json in utf8...

Comment: Also, are you aware of the unicode module in the standard library?

Comment: EEP 10 seems to be marked as accepted. Not sure if it has any relation to Starling...

Comment: I didn't read the entire eep word for word, but the suggested api seems to be the one that's implemented in the unicode module of current erlang releases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This page:

http://erlang.org/doc/highlights.html

...lists hightlights of release 5.7/OTP R13A. Note this passage:

> **1.2 Unicode support**
>
> Support for Unicode is implemented as
>   described in EEP10. Formatting and
>   reading of unicode data both from
>   terminals and files is supported by
>   the io and io_lib modules. Files can
>   be opened in modes with automatic
>   translation to and from different
>   unicode formats. The module 'unicode'
>   contains functions for conversion
>   between external and internal unicode
>   formats and the re module has support
>   for unicode data. There is also
>   language syntax for specifying string
>   and character data beyond the
>   ISO-latin-1 range.

I don't like to make pronouncements on what best practices would be, but I often find it helpful to have a minimal, complete example to start to generalize from. Here's one of getting utf into an erlang application and sending it out again to a different context. Assuming you had a MySql database with a row field in a table containing utf8 characters, here's one way to get it out and pipe it to a web browser as json:

```
hg clone http://bitbucket.org/justin/webmachine/ webmachine-read-only
cd webmachine-read-only
make
./scripts/new_webmachine.erl mywebdemo /tmp
svn checkout http://erlang-mysql-driver.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ erlang-mysql-driver-read-only
cd erlang-mysql-driver-read-only/src
cp * /tmp/mywebdemo/src
svn checkout http://mochiweb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ mochiweb-read-only
cp mochiweb-read-only/src/mochijson2.erl /tmp/mywebdemo/src
cd /tmp/mywebdemo
```

Edit src/mywebdemo_resource.erl so it looks like this:

```
-module(mywebdemo_resource).
-export([init/1, to_html/2]). 

-include_lib("webmachine/include/webmachine.hrl").

init([]) -> {ok, undefined}.

to_html(ReqData, State) ->
    mysql:start_link(pool_id, "database.host.com", 3306, "db_user", "db_password", "db_name", fun(A, B, C, D) -> ouch end, utf8), %% add your connection string info
    {data, Res} = mysql:fetch(pool_id, "select * from table where IdWhatever = 13"),
    [[_, Utf8Str, _]] = mysql:get_result_rows(Res), %% pattern will need to be altered to match your table structure
    {mochijson2:encode({struct, [{Utf8Str, 100}]}), ReqData, State}.
```

Build everything and start the url dispatcher:

```
make
./start.sh
```

Then execute the following in a web page (or something more convenient, like MozRepl):

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
req.open('GET', "http://localhost:8000", false);
req.send(null);
eval("(" + req.responseText + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous poster mentioned the latest release of erlang supports utf natively. If you can't use the latest though then one thing I do usually is to use binaries for string data. It keeps erlang from mangling the bytes in a list. It has the side effect of making lists of strings easier to handle as well.